# HTK HEREST ISSUE

Tags: cmd, speech-recognition, htk

I'm doing some speech recognition using HTK (HMM ToolKit) and I'm getting this odd error:

> ERROR [+7390]  StepAlpha: Alpha prune failed sq(16) > qHi(15)

I have tried to play around with pruning but only those 15/16 would change to other numbers, I keel receiving the same error. I've even tried to disable pruning and it keeps giving me this error.

I just don't know where to look for anything, if I knew I could fix it.

this is my HERest command:

> HERest -C config -I Label.mlf -t 250 100 1000 -S trainlist.scp -H hmms\0\vFloors -H hmms\0\hmm0 -M hmms\1 wordlist

I've looked into the HTK book but there is nothing about the error number 7390.

Answer (score 2):

I work with the HTK toolkit off and on, but not with HEREST. I also have never seen the error that you have encountered. A quick search on the web reveals some links that may be helpful.

1. [Link 1](http://www.ee.uwa.edu.au/~roberto/research/speech/local/entropic/HAPIBook/node275.html#SECTION06310000000000000000)

Scroll to the bottom of the link above, and you see an error code like ??9?. This means that a sanity check has failed. It further says that the error has nothing to do with your code, but that the HTK itself may be faulty. I think, given that Error 7390 has not occurred any where else, and that it also fits your error code, you might want to consider re-installing HTK.

1. [Link 2](http://www.ling.ohio-state.edu/~bromberg/htk_problems.html)
   The link above shows a lot of common errors and its causes seen when working with the HTK toolkit. The original poster has painstakingly put up errors and common conditions that cause them. Saved me a lot of effort. In my eyes, she deserves the Nobel (or something like that).
2. [Link 3](http://www.ee.uwa.edu.au/~roberto/research/speech/local/entropic/HAPIBook/node276.html)
   This link gives more detailed, module by module error codes. Also worth a look.

Do let me know here how you were able to solve your problem.
HTH,
Sriram.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was related to big (15 MB) file in input data. It worked after deleting it. Run HERest with `-T 1` option to see which file causes problem, then remove or split it.

Answer (score 0):

You must adjust `-t` parameter. This error occur when pruning is failed, so with modify prune parameter. I have this problem and with `-t 10` it's solved!